# Use Green's Theorem to evaluate a line integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem, iterated-integrals

> Evaluate the line integral $\int_cy^4\ dx+2xy^3\ dy$ where $C$ is the ellipse $x^2+2y^2=2$.

My attempt:

First, I need Green's Theorem:

> $\int_cP\ dx+Q\ dy = \int\int_D\big(\frac{\partial{Q}}{\partial{x}}-\frac{\partial{P}}{\partial{y}}\big)\ dA$ where $C$ is a positively oriented, smooth, closed curve and let $D$ be the region bound by $C$ in the plane.

Therefore, my region $D$ is the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{(\sqrt{2})^2}+y^2=1$. My bounds for $D$ would then be $-\sqrt{2}\leq x \leq \sqrt{2},\space and \space 0\leq y \leq\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}$.

I realize though that this is only the upper half of the ellipse, so I multiply my integral by $2$ $\therefore$

$$2\int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}}-2y^3\ dy\ dx$$

However, after evaluating this integral, my result is $\frac{22\sqrt{2}}{15}$ when it should be $0$. Is it incorrect to multiply the integral by $2$ when I should instead be integrating in the $y$ direction from $$-{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}}\leq y \leq{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}}$$

Comment: You cannot multiply by two here because $f(y)=-2y^3 \neq f(-y)$.

Comment: Yes it's incorrect to multiply by 2. When you take your first antiderivatives you get an even function of y which whenever you evaluate and even function$f(a)-f(-a)=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You decided to use Green's theorem to compute the given line integral $J$, and arrived at
$$J=\int_D-2y^3\>{\rm d}(x,y)\ ,\tag{1}$$
where $D:=\{(x,y)\,|\,x^2+2y^2\leq2\}$ is the elliptical disc bounded by $C$. Now the integral $(1)$ is $=0$ by symmetry since $D$ is symmetric with respect to the $x$-axis, and the integrand $-2y^3$ is an odd function of $y$.

You can replace $\int_{-b}^b f(y)\>dy\ $ by $\ 2\int_0^b f(y)\>dy$ only if $f$ is an even function of $y$.